# New company acquired running SBS requires access to HQ's domain resources possible?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-sbs

Hi Serverfault Universe!

Our medium sized company recently acquired a new company in a remote office with its own domain running Windows Small Business server on their own domain (NEW_DOMAIN).  I manage an Active Directory domain (MYDOMAIN) with a majority of servers running Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard.

The remote office needs to access MYDOMAIN ‘s resources such as the SharePoint and intranet site.

Is it not possible to form a domain trust on Small Business server?

What would the least disruptive method be for the new office to access my domain’s resources without having to setup a new domain controller on the remote office’s site and have the user’s converted over to our domain (MYDOMAIN)?

UPDATE ::::::::

So it turns out there is an ADDITIONAL Domain Controller in NEW_DOMAIN which is running Windows Server 2008 Standard! Excusing my lack of knowledge of SBS, I was not aware that this type of setup (having a standard DC along with a SBS one) was possible. So given this, it should be possible setup a site trust relationship with MYDOMAIN?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware you cannot have trust relationships with SBS 2003, which would have been useful here.  If you don't mind spending some pennies then you could purchase the SBS 2003 transition pack which will migrate the SBS 2003 domain to a Windows 2003 domain.  More info can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555073)

Comment: +1 - You cannot create Trusts on a SBS server - Transition is all you can do other than migrate/build a new DC for the company

Comment: In addition, you can use the SBS Migration Kit, found here: http://www.sbsmigration.com

Comment: +1 I'd highly recommend migrating to a Standard server.

Comment: So it turns out there is an ADDITIONAL Domain Controller in NEW_DOMAIN which is running Windows Server 2008 Standard! Excusing my lack of knowledge of SBS, I was not aware that this type of setup (having a standard DC along with a SBS one) was possible. So given this, it should be possible setup a site trust relationship with MYDOMAIN?

Comment: You can have additional DC's in SBS domains but that doesn't change the "no Trusts" rule.  You can remove the SBS server and migrate all roles/shares/etc to the Server 2008 if that box has the resources and the SBS box isn't running Exchange.